# How to override an inner class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

I created an abstract inner class with an abstract method in abstract class.

```
abstract class Qqq{
    abstract fun funQqq()

    inner abstract class InQqq{
        abstract fun funInQqq (s:String)
    }
}
```

When I inherit this class, I don't know how to `override` an inner class and its method.

```
class testPhrase:Qqq(){

    override fun funQqq() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override class inQqq{
       //??
    }
}
```

I make it for dividing classes methods in to logic parts

I want to get this methods something like this:

```
val qqqHeir = Qqq()
qqqHeir.inQqq.funInQqq("S")
```

I understand this is something about having instan in class but don't get how to implement it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm interested in exactly what drove you to this idea :) Why the inner class' need?

Comment: I want to create phrases generator. Phrases can be positive negative and question types. Each of this type must be in past future and present tense. So I can call methods this way `phrase.future.getQestionPhrase()`

Comment: Why not lean towards more of a "composition over inheritance" field? This way you can inject a "useCase" (name it whatever you want) that resolves the part of the phrase you're trying to "generate" for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot override an inner class but you can extend it.

```
class testPhrase: Qqq(){

    override fun funQqq() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    inner class MyInQqq: InQqq(){
        override fun funInQqq(s: String) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }

}
```